# How to connect Arduino Lilypad USB to MicroSD breakout board?

Tags: arduino

I'm trying to connect the Arduino Lilypad USB to a MicroSD breakout board. I'm unsure which pins to use for the CS, DI, DO and CLK connections on the MicroSD board.
[image]

[image]

Comment: do you see the 2x3 holes? solder a header to it. it is an ICSP header with SPI pins

Comment: Will the normal Arduino Lilypad ATmega 328p not have this issue?

Comment: what issue? the pins are there. you only need to add the 2x3 header

Comment: It won't be suitable for my project, as I want to use e-sewing.

Comment: the solder wires into the holes

Comment: normal Lilipad has SPI pins on 'ring'